How can I match a smart chip using SUMIF?
I have a column of people smart chips in a spreadsheet, and I want to use them in the range of a SUMIF, but I can't get them to match any value I provide as the criterion. I've tried the string value of the chip (e.g. "John Doe"), and I've tried the corresponding email address (e.g. "johndoe@gmail.com"), but I can't get anything to match the smart chip. The only thing that has worked is referencing a cell that contains a smart chip. How can I match a smart chip for the purposes of functions like EQ, COUNTIF, and SUMIF?


Here's one possible approach you may test out:
=sumif(map(A:A,lambda(Σ,indirect(cell("address",Σ)).name)),"mads",B:B)



If you want to search by email_address, replace .name in the formula with .email
DOCUMENTATION to the aforementioned parameters can be found in the Support Article here


Thanks, it works! it would be great if you could link to the documentation where you found .name and .email in your answer.

Added the support page url now...

The quick answer is =IF(A1.name="John Doe","Do something") for people smart chips. Details and can be found in the extract data with syntax section of the support article. The fields you can extract can be found in the same article at the bottom under Types of data you can extract.
